# mahalanobis distance in Kmeans Clustering using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, cluster-analysis

I have done **Kmeans** clustering and found out the Cluster centers using **OpenCV** C++ API.

```
kmeans(data_points, clusterCount, labels, TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, cluster_centers);
```

Then I'm using **euclidean distance** to **find closest cluster** for a **new data point** against all **cluster centers**.

```
int distance = find_EucledianDist(new_datapoint, cluster_centers);
```

How would I use **Mahalanobis Distance** instead of **Euclidean Distance**? I know I have to calculate Covariance Matrix and Invert it and find Mahalanobis Distance.

However, I don't know how I do that and in what ORDER **(find covar matrix, inverted matrix of which data/matrix)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't this link help you a lot? :)

http://books.google.fr/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA475&lpg=PA475&dq=mahalanobis+opencv&source=bl&ots=hSG09ijHLe&sig=H359_fRI53Pg12dYLOVUJpopb0g&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=O-JMT9-oAYem0AXIpL2eBQ&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=mahalanobis%20opencv&f=false

This would be : 
[CalcCovarMatrix](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#calccovarmatrix), followed by [cvInvert](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#invert), and finally [cvMahalanobis](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#mahalonobis).

Comment: it does exactly what you want, and gives the corresponding opencv function for each step :).

Comment: And just use the opencv Mahalanobis function (I edited your answer)

Comment: Do we have to do CalcCovarMatrix and cvInvert for each cluster and then find cvMahalanobis distance to each and every cluster?

Comment: yes, you do CalcCovarMatrix and cvInvert once for each cluster, and then call cvMahalanobis for each new point against all clusters and select the minimum.

Comment: You really should have posted up the code as google books is not really a good way to display an answer as most people can't see the pages.